# System of nonlinear polynomial equations

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How to solve the system 
\begin{equation}\frac{24 - x^2}{10x} = -\frac{13 - y^2}{12y}~~~~~~~~~~~~~~(1)\\
 x^2 + y^2 + 12 = z^2~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~(2)\\ \frac{z^2 - x^2 - y^2}{2xy} = -\frac{z^2 - 61}{60}~~~~~(3)\end{equation}

Comment: Is any condition given on $x,y,z$ ? Do they belong to the set of Real Numbers or are they Integers ?

Comment: Maple 13.02 solves it. There are real solutions which are simply expressed. But Maple does not show the steps of solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Substitute for $z^2$ from the second equation into the third equation to eliminate $z$ from the system.

$$
\frac{24 - x^2}{10x} = -\frac{13 - y^2}{12y}\\
\frac{6}{xy} = -\frac{x^2+y^2-49}{60}
$$
Now, if you let $y=nx$ for some $n$, then this can be written as
$$
\frac{24-x^2}{5}=-\frac{13-n^2x^2}{6n}\\
\frac{6}{nx^2} = -\frac{x^2(1+n^2)-49}{60}
$$
This is now a pair of equations in $n$ and $x^2=X$. Multiplying up to remove denominators, you have
$$
6n(24-X)=-5(13-n^2X)\\
360 = -nX((1+n^2)X-49)
$$
The first equation is linear in $X$, giving
$$
X=\frac{144n+65}{(6+5n)n}
$$
This can be substituted into the second equation and rearranged to, ultimately, get a quartic for $n$. One of the factors of the quartic is $6n+5$, from which we get $n=-\frac56$. The remaining cubic has one real root, around $n\approx-0.285$. From there, you can work back and get
$$
x=\sqrt{\frac{144n+65}{(6+5n)n}}\\
y=nx\\
z=\sqrt{12+x^2+y^2}
$$
For $n=-\frac56$, we have
$$
x = \pm 6\\
y = \mp 5\\
z = \sqrt{73} \text{ or } -\sqrt{73}
$$
but then $z$ is imaginary. For $n\approx-0.285$, we have
$$
x^2 \approx -18.335
$$
which is, of course, not consistent with a real $x$. Therefore, the solutions for $n=-\frac56$ are the only real solutions.

Comment: I obtain the equation $20736n^4-7560*n^3-11700n^2+12570*n+4225=0$ in this way. Its roots are $-.8333333333, -.2852604546, .7415885607-.5542255536i, .7415885607+.5542255536i.$ However, I vote up your answer.

Comment: Hmmm, seems that I might have made a typo somewhere along the line when I was working out the quartic. I'll update to correct it.

Comment: OK, updated. There's just one set of solutions, all from $n=\frac56$.